# working with files in web application

Tags: jsf

In my web application I am creating a file that eventually the user will download.
This file should be stored in the memory until the user will download it.

So I am using File.createTempFile() for this task.

Is it a good approach or maybe there is a better why for creating files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a good approach but you must know that creating temp files actually means that the file is [created on the disk](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29), not in memroy.

Also [deleting it when the VM terminates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) may be another good step.